# Identify $\mathbb R^4$ with the quaternionic field $\mathbb H$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, quaternions

I would like to identify $\mathbb R^4$ with the quaternionic field $\mathbb H$. 
Then, this identification is given by :
$$ (*) \quad \mathbb H \ni q= a +i b + j c + k d   \longleftrightarrow  (z,w) \in \mathbb C^2;\,  z=a+i b, w=c+i d,$$
or by
$$ (**) \quad \mathbb H \ni q= a +i b + j c + k d   \longleftrightarrow  (z,w) \in \mathbb C^2; \,  z=a+i c, w=b+i d,$$
or other identification ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: As vector spaces either choice is fine, as long as the additive structure is preserved.

Comment: Identify them.... *as what*?

Comment: These are essentially the same because you can permute the three quaternionic units without changing any arithmetic.

Answer (score 2):

(*) is closer to what tends to be useful. The reason is that $q=z+wj$ with this setup. Alternatively one can set

$$ (*) \quad \mathbb H \ni q= a +i b + j c + k d   \longleftrightarrow  (z,w) \in \mathbb C^2;\,  z=a+i b, w=c-i d,$$

due to the fact that $$q=z+jw$$ in this case.